# Can I use regex named group while using re.sub in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to use groups while using `re.sub`. The below works fine.

```
dt1 = "2026-12-02"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})')
m = pattern.match(dt1)
print(m.group('year'))
print(m.group('month'))
print(m.group('day'))
repl = '\\3-\\2-\\1'
print(re.sub(pattern, repl, dt1))
```

Output is

> 02-12-2026

My query is instead of using group numbers can we use group names as:
        \day-\month-\year

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a pretty straight up syntax for accesing groups, using `\g<group name>`

```
import re
dt1 = "2026-12-02"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})')
print(pattern.sub(r"\g<day>-\g<month>-\g<year>", dt1))

Output: '02-12-2026'
```

Comment: Awesome. This is what I was looking for. Thanks @FlyingTeller

Answer (score 4):

```
dt1 = "2026-12-02"
from datetime import datetime
print datetime.strptime(dt1, "%Y-%m-%d").strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

There is no need for regex here.

Output:

`02-12-2026`

But if you want to use regex then here it goes,

```
dt1 = "2026-12-02"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?P<year>\d{4})-(?P<month>\d{1,2})-(?P<day>\d{1,2})')
m = pattern.match(dt1)
def repl(matchobj):
    print matchobj.groupdict()
    return matchobj.group('year')+"-"+matchobj.group('month')+"-"+matchobj.group('day')
print(re.sub(pattern, repl, dt1))
```

Comment: Hi, I am trying to achieve the same using re.sub() and using named groups.

Comment: @setushwetank, any reason why you don't want to use the `datetime` module?